# Blank screen when building React Native app in release mode of android

Tags: react-native, debugging, build, release

I am building a React Native app and it works fine in debug mode, but when I try to build it in release mode, it shows a blank screen. I have tried several things to troubleshoot the issue, such as updating my dependencies and checking for any syntax errors, but I haven't been able to find the cause of the problem. I am not seeing any error messages, and the app seems to be working as expected in debug mode.

I am not sure what is causing the issue in release mode, and I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I have checked that my React Native dependencies are up-to-date and correctly configured.
- I have ensured that the bundle is being correctly packaged in the binary APK.
- I have verified that there are no syntax errors in my code.

Comment: @ Hasina can you verify that you have build a release apk.
i have faced similar issue in react native for ios where debug executable is check

Comment: @OuneebUrRehman Yes, I have verified that the binary file I generated is properly signed with the apksigner verify ---print-certs command. This command displays the certificates that were used to sign the file.

Comment: is the issue exist for android or ios?

Comment: the error occurs on android.

Comment: Turning off dev mode seemed to fix the issue. Does anyone know why this might be happening, and if there are any other potential solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this error handler https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler to catch problems in production. It supports both JS and Native side errors